# Allow entry to the view from stateProvider

Tags: angularjs, jwt

I'm working with JWT logon and angularjs, and I want to see if I can save the session and from my app.js validate and letting in sight if your session is valid, it somehow exits from $ state properties evaluated before showing the view?

Something like this:

```
  .state('dashboard.notifications',{
    templateUrl:'views/ui-elements/notifications.html',
    url:'/notifications'
    session: if(session = true){
      $state.go('notifications');}
       else{$state.go('auth');}}

})
```

Comment: use a `resolve` at parent state of all states that require authorization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$stateChangeStart` or `$stateChangeSuccess` event to do it. For example:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(e, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
   if(fromState.name=='dashboardNotification' && $rootScope.session != true) {
          $state.go('auth');
          e.preventDefault();
   }
});
```